# Sending personalized push notifications using onesignal

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, onesignal

We are working on personalizations on each and every aspect of user interaction and want to send personalized push notifications to the users, meaning each user will receive different notification personalized to him.

We are currently using Onesignal, So can I use Onesignal to send personalized notification upto over then a million user base ? Or I have to migrate to some other alternatives, if so please suggest some reliable solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneSignal can certainly be used to send personalized notifications to each user.

To implement this you will need to call the OneSignal API for each user that you are sending the notification to. Since this might take a while to send to 1 million devices, you can parallelize your API calls to do it faster.

Note that you should not make more than 20 requests per second though, since OneSignal's API may throttle requests from the same API that exceed this limit.

Comment: It will take more then a day to send one million notifications this way, That's not scalable approach. I would definitely need bulk api in this case, but couldn't find any. And tracking would be difficult, since have to check open-rates of each notification.

Comment: I think there should be notification handler, when receive a notification then you can replace specific placeholders pre set in the notification. Idk if `NotificationClicked` method exist in the current oneSignal SDK can be used for that purpose or another method needed.

Comment: @pankaj In the future OneSignal will support tag substitution so this can be done in one API request, but unfortunately this is the only supported method for personalized notifications at this time.