# Amazon SNS SDK Invalid Parameter exception on subscription confirmation

Tags: android, amazon-sns

I'm trying to subscribe an Android user to receive push notifications using this code:

```
 public static void subscribeToTopic(final String topicArn, String EndpointArn) {
        SubscribeRequest request = new SubscribeRequest(topicArn, "application" , EndpointArn);
        SubscribeResult response = getInstance().subscribe(request);
        ConfirmSubscriptionRequest confirmation = new ConfirmSubscriptionRequest(topicArn, response.getSubscriptionArn());
        try {
            getInstance().confirmSubscription(confirmation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: " + e);
        }
    }
```

However, I get the following exception on `confirmSubscription()`:

> 10-15 15:39:59.453: D/(31274): UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION:
>   com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid
>   token (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidParameter; Request ID: 742123aa-6dce-52f2-b2de-6f127516ec56)

However, the subscription IS a success and I succeeded to send push notifications to the app.

Any idea why I get this error ? Is it because confirmation is unnecessary on for this protocol ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android endpoints (and all mobile endpoints) are automatically confirmed when `Subscribe` completes. You do not need to invoke `ConfirmSubscription` for these endpoints.

Comment: Ok, I though so but couldn't find it in the documentation. Thank you !

Comment: @Rohan were you able to unsubscribe from a topic on android? My subscription is ok and receiving notifications, but i am not able to unsubscribe