# How to post to several endpoints in one publish request?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm using SNS for push notifications for android and iOS. Since sending to both devices require different platform application, my endpoints are saved separately. How do I send push notification to all endpoints via SNS publish api in on request instead of many, please?

I've read that using Topics would give me that result, but from what I read, I need them (users) to accept (confirm) that they would like to get notifications..Isn't it going to complicate things, since users already accept notification when app first started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mobile applications you don't need a confirmation in order to subscribe an endpoint to a topic. See it in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376492/amazon-sns-sdk-invalid-parameter-exception-on-subscription-confirmation), so you can indeed use a topic to send a push notification to all endpoints. But beware of topic limits, they used to be 10000 endpoints per topic, but [now it's 10000000](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#limits-restrictions) wich should be more than enough

Comment: Yes I know. There 2 platform applications. One for iOS and one for Android. But the publish method requests endpoint only.

Comment: So if Topics isn't going to work well, what can I use? How can I send a notification to all my users? please

Comment: You should store the ARNs on your database and then use them as endpoints to send the messages (you could request the endpoints before sending the messages but it'd be inneficient)

Comment: Currently, I'm storing the endpoints of my database, and using the publish api I'm sending the same message to each endpoint. It's a lot of requests and it's pointless since there got to be a way to narrow it to one or two requests.

Comment: in my database*

Comment: oh sorry, I've made some reasearch now and it seems Topics are a lot better you can use them for mobile applications without confirmation. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you, that helped !